# Container not stretching to width of page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a container that I'm setting to be absolutely positioned on a page because I want it to float over the background content. The problem is that the container is not 100% of the width of the screen. As a result, even though the `col widths` are appropriate and the content is in fact centered in the row, it appears totally off.

Any thoughts?

[image]

View code:

```
<div class="container home-marketing">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 jumbotron-marketing-wrapper">
      <p class="jumbotron-marketing">Rent the gear you need to get outside</p>
      <p class="jumbotron-marketing">We deliver & pickup even last minute requests</p>
      <p class="jumbotron-marketing">Save money, save time, save space</p>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
/* NOTE adding width: 100% does NOT help */

@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
  .home-marketing {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 65%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){
  .home-marketing {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 20%;
  } 
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 961px){
  .home-marketing {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top:27%;
  }
}
```

Rendered HTML

You can see that the home-marketing container is different because the computed width is 646.661926269531px, but for the navbar for example, the computed width is 970px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are adding class container to absolute element?

```
.home-marketing{
  width:100%;
}

<div class="home-marketing">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 jumbotron-marketing-wrapper">
      <p class="jumbotron-marketing">Rent the gear you need to get outside</p>
      <p class="jumbotron-marketing">We deliver & pickup even last minute requests</p>
      <p class="jumbotron-marketing">Save money, save time, save space</p>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```